# COBOL embedded SQL

Tags: sql, cobol, mainframe

I have a weird problem.

```
         EXEC SQL SELECT                             
         AVG(LER)                                   
         INTO :LER-MIN                              
         FROM CENSUS.WORLDIMR                       
   *     WHERE CENSUS.WORLDIMR.COUNTRY LIKE 'L%'    
         END-EXEC.
```

This is giving out 72.2 but when I use

```
WHERE CENSUS.WORLDIMR.COUNTRY LIKE 'L%'
```

it gives out 00.0.

However trying this in SPUFI:

```
select avg(ler)                              
from census.worldimr                         
where census.worldimr.country like 'L%';
```

Is giving out 71.33333333333.

What did I do wrong?

This is the program:

```
000001        PROCESS SQL                                                      
000002        IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                                         
000003        PROGRAM-ID. CBL7.                                                
000004       *--------------------                                             
000005        ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                            
000006       *--------------------                                             
000007        CONFIGURATION SECTION.                                           
000008        INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                                            
000009        FILE-CONTROL.                                                    
000010            SELECT P3OUT ASSIGN TO UT-S-P3OUT.                           
000011                                                                         
000012        DATA DIVISION.                                                   
000013       *-------------                                                    
000014        FILE SECTION.                                                    
000015        FD  P3OUT                                                        
000016            RECORD CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS                                
000017            LABEL RECORDS ARE OMITTED                                    
000018            RECORDING MODE F                                             
000019            DATA RECORD IS PRTREC.                                       
000020                                                                         
000021        01 PRTREC.                                                       
000022           02 LER-PRT              PIC 99.9.                             
000023           02 FILLER               PIC X(76).                            
000024                                                                         
000025        WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                         
000026        01  VARS.                                                        
000027            10 LER-MIN              PIC S9(5)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000028                                                                         
000029             EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA  END-EXEC.                           
000030       ******************************************************************
000031       *        TABLE(CENSUS.WORLDIMR)                                  *
000032       ******************************************************************
000033            EXEC SQL DECLARE CENSUS.WORLDIMR TABLE                       
000034            ( REGION                         CHAR(5) NOT NULL,           
000035              COUNTRY                        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,          
000036              YR                             CHAR(4) NOT NULL,           
000037              IMR                            DECIMAL(5, 1) NOT NULL,     
000038              IMRM                           DECIMAL(5, 1) NOT NULL,     
000039              IMRF                           DECIMAL(5, 1) NOT NULL,     
000040              IMR1_4                         DECIMAL(5, 1) NOT NULL,     
000041              IMR1_4M                        DECIMAL(5, 1) NOT NULL,     
000042              IMR1_4F                        DECIMAL(5, 1) NOT NULL,     
000043              IMR_5                          DECIMAL(5, 1) NOT NULL,     
000044              IMR_5M                         DECIMAL(5, 1) NOT NULL,     
000045              IMR_5F                         DECIMAL(5, 1) NOT NULL,     
000046              LER                            DECIMAL(5, 1) NOT NULL,     
000047              LERM                           DECIMAL(5, 1) NOT NULL,     
000048              LERF                           DECIMAL(5, 1) NOT NULL      
000049            ) END-EXEC.                                                  
000050       ******************************************************************
000051       * COBOL DECLARATION FOR TABLE CENSUS.WORLDIMR                    *
000052       ******************************************************************
000053        01  WORLDIMR.                                                    
000054            10 REGION               PIC X(5).                            
000055            10 COUNTRY              PIC X(30).                           
000056            10 YR                   PIC X(4).                            
000057            10 IMR                  PIC S9(4)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000058            10 IMRM                 PIC S9(4)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000059            10 IMRF                 PIC S9(4)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000060            10 IMR1-4               PIC S9(4)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000061            10 IMR1-4M              PIC S9(4)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000062            10 IMR1-4F              PIC S9(4)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000063            10 IMR-5                PIC S9(4)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000064            10 IMR-5M               PIC S9(4)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000065            10 IMR-5F               PIC S9(4)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000066            10 LER                  PIC S9(4)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000067            10 LERM                 PIC S9(4)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000068            10 LERF                 PIC S9(4)V9(1) USAGE COMP-3.         
000069                                                                         
000070        PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                              
000071       *------------------                                               
000072            EXEC SQL SELECT                                              
000073             AVG(LER)                                                    
000074             INTO :LER-MIN                                               
000075             FROM CENSUS.WORLDIMR                                        
000076             WHERE CENSUS.WORLDIMR.COUNTRY LIKE 'L%'                     
000077             END-EXEC.                                                   
000078            OPEN OUTPUT P3OUT.                                           
000079            MOVE LER-MIN TO LER-PRT.                                     
000080            WRITE PRTREC.                                                
000081            CLOSE P3OUT.                                                 
000082            STOP RUN.
```

Comment: Are you sure you connect to the same DB/Server?

Comment: Very odd. Are you sure you are connected to the same database, as the same user?

Comment: Yes im sure. Everytime i try to use WHERE CENSUS.WORLDIMR.COUNTRY LIKE 'L%' its displaying 00.0

Comment: L followed by 29 %s. Or use a "varchar"-like host-variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manuals are great things, especially when a search-engine can hit straight into them:

> db2 sql like

The first hit should take you to a manual presented to your through the IBM Knowledge Centre. It is for DB2 11.0, so you should make an obvious change if you are not using 11.0.

Reading, you'll come to:

> If the pattern is specified in a fixed-length string variable, any
>   trailing blanks are interpreted as part of the pattern. Therefore, it
>   is better to use a varying-length string variable with an actual
>   length that is the same as the length of the pattern. *If the host
>   language does not allow varying-length string variables, place the
>   pattern in a fixed-length string variable whose length is the length
>   of the pattern*.
>
> For more information about the use of host variables with specific
>   programming languages, see Host variables.

The language you are using, COBOL, does not allow varying-length string variables (one of the things which makes it so fast, so don't complain).

So, your constant (literal in COBOL) for the LIKE needs to be the same length as the column involved, and all the additional positions in the literal need to be % as well (at least up to the end of the actual maximum length of any data which will match the LIKE, strictly).

Or, use a COBOL host-variable of that length, again padded with trailing %s instead of trailing spaces.

Or use a varchar-like host-variable (a COBOL table with items contain the length of data as a two-byte binary, with a value of 2, and then your `L%`).

```
01 varchar-host-variable.
    05  vhv-length               COMP-5 PIC 9(4).
    05  vhv-data                        PIC XX.
```

Even if the literal worked as you expected (without reading the manual) it is generally a bad idea to have "significant" literals in the PROCEDURE DIVISION. Second reason to use a host-variable.

Comment: In my book, the main advantage of fixed-length variables is that the memory footprint of the program is defined at compile time, which makes memory leaks impossible. Makes exploitation really much safer. But yes, it has a few performances advantages as well.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z Even with variable-length fields, you can't get memory leaks at all in Enterprise COBOL if you stick to COBOL (subject to compiler errors). By exploitation, you mean something hijacking something from the program?  Except for someone working at the site, when it would be only be massively difficult, it is impossible from an external location. Of course, mileage varies with other less mature OSs and other compilers.

Comment: No, I was just speaking about the people who launch & watch over hundreds of procecesses in the same time. They don't like to see a process eating all the memory space useful for others. Hijacking, otoh, is not a question of language, and the risk usually begins when you think there is no risk.